# a SSRS 2008 problem:How to sum with a condition

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a SSRS report in which there is two column Current_Product and TempAnnSaving.
Current_product has value current product and thier match. that means each current product have a match row or it may be more than one row.Each match row has a TempAnnSaving value in TempAnnSaving column.Now at the end of the report i have to show the total sum of TempannSaving,but there is a condition for sum--i have to sum only first match of each current product .
here is image http://www.imgplace.com/viewimg121/4385/96unled.png

Answer (score 0):

aI guess that the "Current Product" is in the group, if so then do SUM provided by 
`=IIF (CountRows (Filed!namefield, "nameGroup") = 1, SUM (Field!namefield, "nameGroup"),Nothing)`